# Is there any way to change an outside object from inside a function

Tags: c++, object-reference

Is it possible to define a function which will make the argument refer to another (already existing) object after it returns without using pointers, etc? Again, this can't just change the existing object by using a copy constructor or assignment operator or anything. The outside object would refer to a different block of memory when the function returned.

For example:

```
int x;
void change(int& blah) {
    blah = x; // I don't want to change blah's value to x's value, I want to make blah refer to x outside the function
}

void main() {
    int something = 0;
    change(something);
    assert(&x == &something);
}
```

Regardless of the method used, the function must be called like

```
change(x);
```

Without applying any special operator or function to the argument before calling the function. I don't know if this is possible, but it would make very cool things possible if it is. If it's not, I would also like to know why.

Comment: not that i know of, i think that the only way to do that is use a pointer. When you pass a variable to a function, a copy of the variable is passed, unless you use pointers

Comment: The kind of reference you are talking about _is_ a pointer. A pointer is used to 'refer to a ... block of memory'. Doing this without pointers seems to be a contradictory request.

Comment: @sje397: A non-pointer variable such as `int x` still refers to a block of memory. It's just that it can't be made to point to anything else, and also doesn't require indirection (since `x` *is* that chunk of memory, so to speak).

Comment: @Ken yeah, that's what I was thinking too, but if it can't be made to point to anything else then that's that. See my other comment on James' answer though.

Comment: @Ken - I get your point and I think you get mine, but if you want to get into that much detail I would argue that `x` in your example refers to the _contents_ of the memory, whereas a pointer actually _does_ refer to the memory itself.

Comment: @sje397 that's a good concise way to think of it I think.

Comment: @sje397: Good point - probably more constructive to think in terms of values rather than locations when it comes to automatically allocated variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because `something` and `x` are different objects.  They don't refer to different objects.  They don't point to different objects.  They *are* different objects.

To change where something points, that something needs to be a pointer.  If you have a pointer, you can do this:

```
int x;

void change(int*& p)
{
    p = &x;
}

int main()
{
    int something = 0;
    int* pointer = &something; // pointer points to 'something'
    change(pointer);           // now pointer points to 'x'
    assert(&x == pointer);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way perhaps it could be done with some implicit casting and stuff? Like, the object could be cast to a pointer and manipulated or something?

Comment: @Seth: Nope, variables can never be moved around in memory.

Comment: @Ken ok, then do you see any other way of solving this problem? I have an array of objects with a _reference_ to one of the objects. I want to make the reference refer to one of the other objects in the array. Is that possible? Or still no? Thanks all for the fast responses.

Comment: No, you need to use a pointer.  You cannot change the object to which a reference refers after you have initialized the reference.

Comment: @James ok, the reason I wanted to do that was to be able to return a subclass of an interface from a pure virtual function (but you can only do that with references or pointers b/c only they are covariant). Now, if you have a virtual function which returns an `ISomething`, is it possible to return a subclass of that, or otherwise make `ISomething` extendable? Or is this problem completely unsolvable with C++?

Comment: No; if a function returns an `ISomething` _by value_, the object that gets returned is of type `ISomething`, not of any derived type.  You must use pointers or references for this.  I don't know what you mean by "is this completely unsolvable?"  Of course it's solvable, but returning an `ISomething` by value is the wrong way to solve the problem.

Comment: @James I need to return something such that `*retval` is the object that the `ISomething` is holding, _not_ the `ISomething`. I don't think that's possible if `retval` is a pointer to an `ISomething` and not an `ISomething`. And by solvable, I mean solvable without adding all kinds of extra stuff, like extra methods that return the subclass and having other ones to return `ISomething`.

Comment: @Seth, this should have been the actual question. You can try it posting and starting a new thread; you may get some better answers.

Comment: @iammilind how should I phrase it? As you can tell, I am particularly bad at asking questions with the right amount of abstraction/specificity.

Comment: @Seth: I take it that the reference to the object is a private data member (or at least protected) in the class? This would be the best design choice, from what I can tell. If that is the case, then change the reference into a pointer (let's say it's called `pObj`). Then, your method can still have a return type of `ISomething &` to support covariance, as long as you just return `*pObj`. Now the pointer can be changed as often as possible, but is only exposed as an alias for an object, so the expression `*retval` will give what you want.

Comment: @Seth, you can go ahead ask. Put some minimal code and also mention why you want to do that. That will be easy to understand. If not then may be someone or I will edit it. :)

Comment: @Ken that would work, **except** to return a reference, the object has to already exist somewhere independently; this is the array I was talking about (I return a reference to an object in the array). Each object in that array holds an element which is the actual data (a reference to which is what gets returned by `*retval`) and I can't implement it as a pointer to the data and change that pointer because then the original one would be lost, and the objects that store the data need to be associated with only one of the data. Keep in mind this is all to support covariance for virtual functions.

Comment: @Seth: Yeah, then I would definitely follow the other recommendations and re-ask this question, with some code specific to this problem of covariance. That way, we can more easily see your design and help out.

Comment: @iammilind and Ken here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6977820/726361 Let me know if you need any more info. And thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Nope definitely not possible. Both regular variables like `int x` and references variables like `int &y(...)` and arrays are not reseatable, i.e. they *always* will use/point to the same chunk of memory.

To obtain the functionality you require, you really need to either use a pointer, or an abstraction of pointers. It's not possible otherwise.

As an attempt at an explanation, here goes (not entirely correct, and grossly simplified, but good enough to get the idea):

When you declare a variable like `int x`, you are really asking for the compiler to associate `x` with a specific region of memory. So, for example, suppose `x` is associated the four-byte starting at `0x439FC2`. Since the compiler knows that `x` should always refer to `0x439FC2`, than any use of `x` can really be replaced by looking up those memory cells, and loading them into registers, pushing them onto the stack, or whatever. Anyways, the end result is that the variable name `x` is pretty much replaced by the number `0x439FC2`. So the reason you can't move `x` around is that you can't make that memory address refer to a different location in memory.

Again, that explanation is simplified and not entirely true, but it is the "intuitive" way of reasoning about automatically allocated variables.

Comment: I hope not to waste your time, but can you give me the entirely correct and grossly unsimplified version?

Comment: @Seth: Unfortunately, that's beyond my skill set.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a reference to a pointer:

```
void change(int &* blah, int * x){

  blah = x;
}

int * num1;
int num2 = 2;

change( num1, &num2 ); //num1 now points to num2
```