# Interfaces and covariance problem

Tags: c++, interface, iterator, covariance

I have a particular class that stores a piece of data, which implements an interface:

```
template<typename T>
class MyContainer : public Container<T> {
    class Something : public IInterface {
    public:
        // implement *, ->, and ++ here but how?
    private:
        T x;
    };

    // implement begin and end here, but how?

private:
    Something* data; // data holds the array of Somethings so that references to them can be returned from begin() and end() to items in this array so the interface will work, but this makes the problem described below
};
```

And I have an array of `Something`s.

I have the need for `Something` to implement an interface class (`IInterface` in the example) which:

1. Contains pure virtual member functions which return something such that `*retval` returns a reference to the `x` member, `retval->` returns the address of `x`, and `++retval` makes `retval` refer to the next `Something` in the array.
2. The things that the pure virtual members return can be inherited from and returned by the implementation of the members
3. `container[i]` (where `container` is the array holding the `Something` objects) always returns something such that `*retval` always returns a reference to the same `T` for the same `i`.

Right now, the interface looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Container {
    class IInterface {
    public:
        virtual T& operator*() = 0;
        virtual T* operator->() = 0;
        virtual IInterface& operator++(); // this is the problem 
    };

    // returning a reference right now to support covariance, so subclasses can
    // derive from Container and then have a member class derive from IInterface
    // and override these to return their derived class, but this has a problem
    virtual IInterface& begin() = 0;
    virtual IInterface& end() = 0;
};
```

My current solution (have the virtual methods return an `IInterface&` and return a `Something&` in the implementation) has no problem with the requirements, **except** for the `++retval` requirement. Because the `Something` is directly tied to the object it holds and can't point to a `T` with a pointer, there's no way that I can find to get `++` to make the variable refer to the next `Something` in the array.

If it helps to know, this is an iterator type system. I would have made it with the STL style iterators (where you just have an array of `T`) that are passed around by value and hold pointers to the values they represent, but that would break the interface because only references and pointers are covariant, and the objects already have to exist somewhere else already (in my code they're in the array) so you don't return a reference to a local object.

The purpose of this setup is so that one can write functions that take a `Container&` and iterate the container without knowing what type of container it is:

```
void iterate(Container<int>& somecontainer) {
    Container<int>::IIterator i = somecontainer.begin(); // right now this would return a reference, but it doesn't/can't work that way
    while (i != somecontainer.end()) {
         doSomething(*i);
         ++i; // this is the problem
    }
}
```

It's kind of difficult for me to describe, don't hesitate to let me know if you need more information.

Comment: +1, you can also provide a bit code about `IInterface` and how the methods related to especially `++retval` looks like in the class.

Comment: @iammilind, I will be glad to provide whatever info I can, but what is "how the methods related to especially `++retval` looks like in the class"? See if my update is what you mean.

Comment: @Cat so that people can write functions that take a `Container&` without knowing what type of container it is, and call `container.begin()` to get a `IInterface&` and iterate over the elements of the container.

Comment: What are the constraints on `T`?  Can `T` be any type?  If so, you'll have to hack it using something like `boost::any`, in which case users of the class need to know what the type of `*container.begin()` is.  It sounds like you really want a template, though.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, but why do you need the interface.

Comment: @James yes the class is a template, but I left that out because I thought it would unnecessarily complicate things for the example. Do I still need `boost::any`? I don't understand what I would need it for. @Cat I already said why I need the interface, so functions can take reference/pointers to the interface without knowing exactly what container it is. You could iterate over linked lists, vectors, etc with the same code. I know this is done by making the functions that take containers templates, but I don't want to do it that way, I need runtime flexibility, not compile time flexibility.

Comment: @James I have updated the example to show the template-ness of the class and the interface.

Comment: @Seth: The point Cat is trying to make (or at least the point **I** would like to make) is that you shouldn't _want_ to iterate over a sequence of elements without knowledge of what container it came from. If you need to do that (for algorithms), then those functions need to be templates, not derived classes. The book Effective C++ has a whole section on why you shouldn't try to ignore differences between containers and iterators.

Comment: @Nicol: I'd like to disagree with ignoring the differences. While template polymorphism is great, it is not the only kind. In fact, I sometimes find myself wanting an standard library which relies much less on templates, and more on class hierarchies for polymorphic behavior. Sometimes, it *does* make sense to ignore differences. Indeed, what other reason is there for having things like abstract classes if not to ignore implementation details (really, what other reason is there in having a class hierarchy at all?).

Comment: You might want to read this *[any_iterator: Implementing C++ Iterator Type Erasure](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html)*. Then again, I would wander in the opposite direction, it is much simpler to make `iterate` a function template that will use regular iterators. You can also find an implementation as part of [adobe libraries](http://stlab.adobe.com/classadobe_1_1any__iterator.html).

Comment: @Ken @James Interestingly, while trying to implement some of you guys' solutions, I found a piece of code which crashes MSVC++ 2010: `template<typename T>class A { class B : public C; };` Is it just me or should I submit a bug report to Microsoft?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called *type erasure*. Basically you want to provide a *value type* (which is the same across the whole inheritance hierarchy) that wraps the particular iterator type and offers a uniform *dynamic* interface.

Type erasure is usually implemented with a non-virtual class (the *type erased*) that stores a pointer to a virtual base class that implements the *erasure*, from which you derive different types that wrap each particular iterator. The static class would offer templated constructor/assignment operators that would *dynamically* instantiate an object of the derived type and store the pointer internally. Then you only need to implement the set of operations as dispatch to the internal object.

For the simplest form of type erasure possible, you can take a look at the implementation of `boost::any` (documentation is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/any.html))

Sketch:

```
namespace detail {
   template<typename T>
   struct any_iterator_base {
      virtual T* operator->() = 0;    // Correct implementation of operator-> is tough!
      virtual T& operator*() = 0;
      virtual any_iterator_base& operator++() = 0;
   };
   template <typename T, typename Iterator>
   class any_iterator_impl : any_iterator_base {
      Iterator it;
   public:
      any_iterator_impl( Iterator it ) : it(it) {}
      virtual T& operator*() {
         return *it;
      }
      any_iterator_impl& operator++() {
         ++it;
         return *this;
      }
   };
}
template <typename T>
class any_iterator {
   detail::any_iterator_base<T>* it;
public:
   template <typename Iterator>
   any_iterator( Iterator it ) : it( new detail::any_iterator_impl<T,Iterator>(it) ) {}
   ~any_iterator() {
      delete it;
   }
   // implement other constructors, including copy construction
   // implement assignment!!! (Rule of the Three)
   T& operator*() {
      return *it;   // virtual dispatch
   }
};
```

The actual implementation becomes really messy. You need to provide different versions of the iterator for the different iterator types in the standard, and the detail of the implementation of the operators might not be trivial either. In particular `operator->` is applied iteratively until a raw pointer is obtained, and you want to make sure that your type erased behavior does not break that invariant or document how you break it (i.e. limitations on the type `T` that your adaptor can wrap)

For extended reading:
 - [On the Tension Between Object-Oriented and Generic Programming in C++](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html)
 - [any_iterator: Implementing Erasure for C++ iterators](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html)
 -  [adobe any_iterator](http://stlab.adobe.com/classadobe_1_1any__iterator.html) ,

Comment: I think this is what I did to get around the problem in the first place. I had `begin` and `end` for when you know what type the container is so you can have all the capabilities of the iterator, and seperate functions that were in the interface. But this was extremely messy like you said, and I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: @Seth The problem you want to solve is not simple, and that means that the solution will be complex. Some of the things I did not mention, and I am not sure whether they are obvious include the fact that you do not need to create a particular container hierarchy, but rather use the `any_iterator` to wrap regular iterators. At any rate, the simple solution is just using a template, and that is what I would advise you to do, but if you *really* want to get away from that, this is the way.

Comment: @David alright, since I don't believe there's a way to do it that will satisfy me, I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks everyone for the effort and time.

Comment: @Seth: I think that the linked articles and code are worth reading, wether you do actually want to try this, or just try to understand the complexity of the problem. Type erasure itself is not *that* complex by itself, but this particular problem is performing type erasure over a set of families of types, while maintaining a *common* interface, and that makes it harder.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a look at the `Visitor` pattern.

Other than that, what you want is a value type that will be imbued with polymorphic behavior. There is a much simpler solution than James' using your `IInterface`.

```
class IInterface
{
  virtual ~IInterface() {}
  virtual void next() = 0;
  virtual void previous() = 0;
  virtual T* pointer() const = 0;

  virtual std::unique_ptr<IInterface> clone() const = 0;
};

std::unique_ptr<IInterface> clone(std::unique_ptr<IInterface> const& rhs) {
  if (!rhs) { return std::unique_ptr<IInterface>(); }
  return rhs->clone();
}

class Iterator
{
  friend class Container;
public:
  Iterator(): _impl() {}

  // Implement deep copy
  Iterator(Iterator const& rhs): _impl(clone(rhs._impl)) {}
  Iterator& operator=(Iterator rhs) { swap(*this, rhs); return *this; }

  friend void swap(Iterator& lhs, Iterator& rhs) {
    swap(lhs._impl, rhs._impl);
  }

  Iterator& operator++() { assert(_impl); _impl->next(); return *this; }
  Iterator& operator--() { assert(_impl); _impl->previous(); return *this; }
  Iterator operator++(int); // usual
  Iterator operator--(int); // usual

  T* operator->() const { assert(_impl); return _impl->pointer(); }
  T& operator*() const { assert(_impl); return *_impl->pointer(); }

private:
  Iterator(std::unique_ptr<IInterface> impl): _impl(impl) {}
  std::unique_ptr<IInterface> _impl;
};
```

And finally, the `Container` class will propose:

```
protected:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IInterface> make_begin() = 0;
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IInterface> make_end() = 0;
```

And implement:

```
public:
  Iterator begin() { return Iterator(make_begin()); }
  Iteraotr end() { return Iterator(make_end()); }
```

*Note:*

You can do away with the `std::unique_ptr` if you can avoid the ownership issue. If you can restrict the IInterface to be behavioral only (by extracting the state into `Iterator`), then you can have the `Strategy` pattern kick-in, and use a pointer a statically allocated object. This way, you avoid dynamic allocation of memory.

Of course, it means your iterators won't be so rich, as it requires `IInterface` implementations to be stateless, and implementing "filtering" iterators, for example, would become impossible.

Comment: Yeah, the thing I am trying to get is that when you know the type of the container, you get all the capabilities of the iterator, but when you don't, you still have access to basic functions.

Comment: This is possible by having several `Iterator` class, one for each "type" of container (I'd guess: `ForwardIterator`, `BidirectionalIterator`, `RandomAccessIterator`). You should avoid inheritance between them, to preserve the value semantics, however if you define an inheritance chain for the corresponding `Interface`s, then you can provide conversion constructors and you can even emulate the `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, the problem is that instances of `Something` are tied to the object it holds. So let's try to untie them.

The key point to remember is that in OOP, public non-const data members are generally frowned upon. In your current implementation, every `Something` instance is tied to having a data member `T x` which is publicly accessible. Instead of this, is considered better to make an abstraction of this, i.e. provide accessor methods instead:

```
class Something : IInterface
{
private:
    T x;

public:
    T GetX()
    {
        return x;
    }
};
```

Now the user has know idea what type of thing `x` is, much less that `x` exists.

This is a good first step, however, since you wish be able to have `x` refer to different objects at different times, we're pretty much going to have to make `x` be a pointer. And as a concession to conventional code, we'll also make `GetX()` return a const reference, rather than a regular value:

```
class Something: IInterface
{
private:
    T *x;

public:
    T const& GetX()
    {
        return *x;
    }
};
```

It's now trivial to implement the methods in `IInterface`:

```
class Something: IInterface
{
private:
   T *x;

public:
    T const& GetX()
    {
        return *x;
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return *x;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        return x;
    }

    Something& operator++()
    {
        ++x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The `++` operator is trivial now - it really just applies the `++` to `x`.

The user now has no idea that a pointer was used. All they know is that their code works right. That's the most important point in OOP's principle of data abstraction.

### Edit

As far as implementing the `begin` and `end` methods of `Container`, that shouldn't be too difficult either, but it will require some changes to `Container`.

First off, let's add a private constructor to `Something` which takes a pointer to the starting object. We'll also make `MyContainer` a friend of `Something`:

class Something: IInterface
    {

```
    friend class MyContainer; // Can't test the code right now - may need to be MyContainer<T> or ::MyContainer<T> or something.

private:
   T *x;

    Something( T * first )
    : x(first)
    {
    }

public:

    T const& GetX()
    {
        return *x;
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return *x;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        return x;
    }

    Something& operator++()
    {
        ++x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

By making the constructor private, and setting the friend dependancy, we ensure that *only* MyContainer can make new `Something` iterators (this protects us iterating over random memory if something erroneous were given by a user).

Next off, we'll change MyContainer a little, so that rather than having an array of `Something`, we'll just have an array of `T`:

```
class MyContainer
{
    ...
private:

    T *data;

};
```

Before we get to implementing `begin` and `end`, let's make that change to `Container` I talked about:

```
template<typename T, typename IteratorType>
class Container {
public:
    ...
    // These prototype are the key. Notice the return type is IteratorType (value, not reference)
    virtual IteratorType begin() = 0;
    virtual IteratorType end() = 0;
};
```

So rather than relying on covariance (which would be *really* difficult in this case), we use a little template magic to do what we want.

Of course, since Container now accepts another type parameter, we need a corresponding change to `MyContainer`; namely we need to provide `Something` as the type parameter to `Container`:

```
template<class T>
class MyContainer : Container<T, Something>
...
```

And the `begin`/`end` methods are now easy:

```
template<class T>
MyContainer<T>::begin()
{
    return Something(data);
}

template<class T>
MyContainer<T>::end()
{
    // this part depends on your implementation of MyContainer.
    // I'll just assume your have a length field in MyContainer.
    return Something(data + length);
}
```

So this is what I've got for my midnight thinking. Like I mentioned above, I cannot currently test this code, so you might have to tweak it a bit. Hopefully this does what you want.

Comment: This answer has very good points in it, and that's basically how STL iterators work. However, the problem is how do I implement `begin` and `end` of the `Container` interface? As it is now, I have to return a `IInterface&`, but to do that, the `Something`s need to exist somewhere, which is what happens now. But for them to exist... etc. Am I being able to communicate that correctly?

Comment: I'll see if I can add something. Let me know if it's not quite what you're looking for.

Comment: this is very nearly what I'm looking for - a combination of virtual methods with CRTP I believe - however, the way this is set up, you need to know the type of container to accept an iterator as an argument, which defeats the purpose of all this hoop-jumping.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). I find it a good candidate here. Here is a brief [demo](http://www.ideone.com/b8BWm). It just explains your `++retval` problem (if I understood it correctly). You have to change your `IInterface` definition from `pure virtual` to CRTP type interface.

```
template<class Derived>
struct IInterface
{
  Derived& operator ++ ()
  {
    return ++ *(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
  }
};

struct Something : public IInterface<Something>
{
  int x;
  Something& operator ++ ()
  {
    ++x;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

There are some limitations of CRTP, that the `template` will always follow your `IInterface`. Which means that if you are passing a `Something` object to a function like this:

```
foo(new Something);
```

Then, `foo()` should be defined as:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(IInterface<T> *p)
{
  //...
  ++(*p);
}
```

However for your problem, it can be a good fit.

Comment: this is a brilliant idea, and I have tried to implement it this way, but there's _one_ sticking point: Say `SomeClass` has derived from `Container` and an inner class called `MyIt` that has derived from `IInterface`. `Container` says that it has a method called `begin` that returns a `IInterface`. The problem I have is that when the caller knows it's a `SomeClass`, it should get a `MyIt` (be it a ref or value), but when it only knows it's a `Container` pointer, it should get back an `IInterface` (be it a ref or value). That's why I needed covariance. Can that it still be done?

Comment: @Ken and iammilind, many thanks for the help, I'll be back tomorrow with a fresh mind to see if this is solvable.

Comment: @Seth, it's possible at some extent. As I mentioned in my answer, that `template` syntax will keep following wherever `IInterface` goes. You have to change the design of your code like that. This is just one of the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If the usage is supposed to be similar to stdlib, then the iterator needs to be a value object, because it normally gets copied by value a lot. (Also, otherwise what would the `begin` and `end` method return a reference to?)

```
template <class T>
class Iterator
{
    shared_ptr<IIterator> it;
public:
    Iterator(shared_ptr<IIterator>);
    T& operator*() { it->deref(); }
    T* operator->() { return &it->deref(); }
    Iterator& operator++() { it->inc(); return *this; }
    etc.
};
```