# CRTP'ed Containers

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I am cutting my teeth at some template programming and I am very new to this. What I want to implement are a few CRTP classes that contain an STL container. Let `class A{};` serve as an example for the (compile time) base class from which `class B{};` and `class C{};` are "derived" at compile time following the CRTP style.

Now both `B` and `C` will contain containers. For the purpose of the example let it be a `std::vector` and a `std::set` respectively. Now, I want to expose the iterators of these via a `begin()` and an `end()` function that exposes a forward iterator. However, I do not want to expose what is the exact container that is inside `B` and `C` and I want to define these functions for `A`, so that at call time the correct one for `B` and `C` get used.

Is this possible ? Right now my plan is to have a `Iterator` inner class for `B` as well as `C` that will contain the actual iterator of (a vector or a set as the case may be) and delegate the call to it. However this seems to be a lot of replicated glue code and I suspect there is a better option.

I have a couple of questions:

1. How do I declare the inner clases in `A`, `B` and `C` so that it plays well with CRTP. Do I need to replicate it for `A`, `B` and `C` ? Can it be an empty class in `A` and I mask them in `B` and `C` with specialized implementations ?
2. How can I expose the iterator with less glue and less duplication ?

I do not want to create dependencies with external libraries like boost and want to stick to std only. So I have to implement whatever extra I need myself. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I assume you want `begin()` and `end()` to be virtual functions in class A right?

Comment: @Seth Carnegie No thats the thing I do not want this classes to have any virtual function at all.

Comment: you are running into a problem that I had as well. You want to pass around Bs and Cs as As right?

Comment: yeah, there's a problem because you're returning a type which is defined in the derived class. There's no way to do this that I know of (because that type doesn't exist when you derive from the base class using CRTP so you get a compile error about the type not being defined) except to use covariance by returning a reference or a pointer, in which case you have to have the memory allocated somewhere else, which ruins the whole thing with iterators. You'll notice that the wikipedia article on CRTP returns `void` for all the examples.

Comment: You can see my question on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977820/interfaces-and-covariance-problem while it doesn't deal with CRTP, one of the answers presents that as a solution but it can't work for the same reason you're having here.

Comment: @Seth Oh bummer! I thought forward iterators being simple as they are, that it would be possible.

Comment: yeah, it sucks. That's probably why the STL classes don't have iterators that derive from a base type, even though it would be so handy to be able to iterate a container without knowing what type it was.

Comment: @Seth thanks for your comments and the link. It was very helpful. Let me sleep over this problem and see if i can simplify my requirments.

Comment: @Seth Just a thought, if the return type of the functions are another template parameter then it might work out, isnt it ?

Comment: no, because the type has to exist when you derive it. That means you can't declare any types inside your class and use them as a template parameter because by the time you define it, its too late. Unless of course the type you're meaning is not a nested class in the derived class.

Comment: @Ah I see. I cannot be lazy about it, that I can put a place holder for it as a template parameter that will eventually become well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you corretcly, you are looking for something like this. Note, I made some simple constructor just to illustrate that it works. Also, your `class A` is mine `class TWrapperBase`, `B` - `TWrapperB`, `C` - `TWrapperC`. Another thing, you don't really need to have two derived classes for this particular example, but I assume your classes `B` and `C` are significantly different to justify it in your program.

EDIT: Forgot to increment lIterSet in the loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

template< typename PType, typename PContainer >
class TWrapperBase
{
 public:
  typedef PType TType;
  typedef PContainer TContainer;
  typedef typename TContainer::iterator TIterator;
 protected:
  TContainer mContainer;
 public:
  TWrapperBase( const TContainer& pOriginal ) :
   mContainer( pOriginal )
  {
  }
  TIterator begin( void )
  {
   return mContainer.begin();
  }
  TIterator end( void )
  {
   return mContainer.end();
  }
};

template< typename PType, class PContainer = std::vector< PType > >
class TWrapperB : public TWrapperBase< PType, PContainer >
{
 public:
  TWrapperB( const TContainer& pOriginal ) :
   TWrapperBase( pOriginal )
  {
  }
};

template< typename PType, class PContainer = std::set< PType > >
class TWrapperC : public TWrapperBase< PType, PContainer >
{
 public:
  TWrapperC( const TContainer& pOriginal ) :
   TWrapperBase( pOriginal )
  {
  }
};

int main( void )
{
 int lInit[] =
 {
 1, 2, 3
 };

 std::vector< int > lVec( lInit, lInit + 3 );
 std::set< int > lSet( lInit, lInit + 3 );

 TWrapperB< int > lB( lVec );
 TWrapperC< int > lC( lSet );

 std::vector< int >::iterator lIterVec = lB.begin();
 std::set< int >::iterator lIterSet = lC.begin();

 while( lIterVec < lB.end() )
 {
  std::cout << "vector: " << *lIterVec << " / set: " << *lIterSet << std::endl;
  lIterVec++;    
  lIterSet++;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ideally would not like to expose the nature of the container type outside, but this is a good alternative solution. Wish I could accept more than 2 answers.

Answer (score 3):

Expose the iterator too via CRTP:

```
template <typename T, typename Iter, typename ConstIter>
struct Base
{
    Iter begin() { return static_cast<T*>(this)->begin(); }
    Iter end() { return static_cast<T*>(this)->end(); }
    ConstIter begin() const { return static_cast<const T*>(this)->begin(); }
    ConstIter end() const { return static_cast<const T*>(this)->end(); }
};


struct B : Base<B, std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator>
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator begin() { return container.begin(); }
    ...

private:
    std::vector<int> container;
};
```

If you have more types to expose, then pass a traits class as a template argument to `Base`:

```
template <typename T, typename Traits>
struct Base
{
    typename Traits::iterator begin() { ... }
    ...
};

// For this purpose, vector<int> makes a perfect traits class !
struct B : Base<B, std::vector<int> >
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator begin() { ... }
    ...
};

// Here is an example function taking Base as argument
template <typename T, typename Traits>
void foo(const Base<T, Traits>& x) 
{
    typename Traits::iterator i = x.begin();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this exactly what I have (i.e. begin and end CRTP'ed too). My problem was how to declare the iterator as they were actually of different types in the different derived classes, but traits and/or template does solve the problem. Thank you.